# no get by Id, want implement getall functionality

Tags: get, return, call

I have multiple get functions returning a list. I want get all those get in one get. Is it good idea to do that? or implement get all individually and call them in get?

Comment: You should at least tag the correct language to get some attention to your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.